# How to make decorators take effect when the program starts - Python

Tags: python

When decorators are applied to methods in other modules, if I want these decoration take effect, I need to load these modules.

Can I let them load when the program start?

I try to import all modules in `main.py` can achieve this goal, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This question makes no sense. If you want to use any code you did not write you have to load a module- that is not specific to decorators. Can you provide a concrete example of your issue with code to illustrate?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem: why do you want the decorated functions to be available? processed? when the program starts, since you can't use them until they're imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little bit unclear what you want (a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a great help), but I'll take a shot at explaining what decorators *are* and *when* their code is run. I'm basically going to be summarizing parts of the excellent [Real Python article on decorators](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/), which you should absolutely read for a complete understanding.

Decorators are just functions. Real Python gives this example:

```py
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapper():
        print("Something is happening before the function is called.")
        func()
        print("Something is happening after the function is called.")
    return wrapper

def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")

say_whee = my_decorator(say_whee)
```

If you run it, it produces the following output:

```
>>> say_whee()
Something is happening before the function is called.
Whee!
Something is happening after the function is called.
```

Now you're probably thinking that I didn't show you a decorator, just a wrapper function. Guess what? Same thing! A decorator is syntatic sugar for what we did above. In fact, we can use the same function in the same way as a decorator:

```py
@my_decorator
def say_whee():
    print("Whee!")
```

So as to when decorators are run, the answer is, "whenever a decorated function is run." There's nothing fancier or more mysterious going on than that. If you want your decorators to run, you need to run the decorated functions. If the decorated thing is a class, the decorator is run each time an instance of the class is instantiated, which, guess what, is achieved by running a function that the decorator(s) wrap.

Hopefully that clears things up a bit. Again, I would highly recommend reading the linked Real Python article for a more complete understanding.

Comment: I don't disagree with anything in this answer, but I disagree with jumping to answers for unclear questions. The value add vs time wasted cost is unfavorable.

Comment: I agree. So the only way I can achieve is to import all decorated methods at the begin of my code file, if I want decorators to  be take effect when my code start rather than when invoke them.

Comment: @songzblink I think you're still misunderstanding. Importing doesn't run anything on its own. Per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), "The import statement combines two operations; it searches for the named module, then it binds the results of that search to a name in the local scope." The only way to run decorator code is to invoke the decorated functions. If you really have some use case where you think decorated code should be run let's call it "statically," you need to update your question with specifics so people can suggest alternatives.

Comment: @flakes While I don't disagree in general, it seemed pretty clear from the question that OP was having an unrelated problem that they were trying to solve with decorators (an XY problem, as was pointed out), but also that they wouldn't be easily disabused of the notion that decorators were the answer without a clear explanation of what they actually do. This answer seemed like a way of moving that process along instead of leaving OP stranded in XY land.

Comment: If the question was "what is a decorator?" then there are plenty posts on SO, blogs, PEPs, and papers, which IMO are better referenced as a comment. I do see that there is value in this answer (as the OP accepted it), however, from experience I caution against answering questions which are evidently vague. These interactions often lead to increased confusion between the answerer and the OP when the real issue is language barrier, lack of context, etc, that should be addressed in the comments. Such vagueness results in limited utility for future readers searching answers to their own problems.

Comment: @flakes That's all valid, and I appreciate the feedback. My take is that if OP is inexperienced, especially e.g. PEPs and papers are going to be overwhelming and thus remain unread. A concise, gentle introduction, even if it's repeated information, can facilitate understanding where a link could not, though you're absolutely right that it can also backfire. My five minutes didn't seem like an inordinate waste of time while I was waiting for something to finish. As for future readers, the jury's out on whether anyone ends up here without an equivalent misunderstanding of the basics.